# Prove $\frac{1}{\log_2(\pi)}+\frac{1}{\log_3(\pi)}+\frac{1}{\log_5(\pi)}<3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove: $$\frac{1}{\log_2(\pi)}+\frac{1}{\log_3(\pi)}+\frac{1}{\log_5(\pi)}<3.$$

I don't have any good idea for this problem. I have tried AM-GM inequality but didn't see the solution.

Answer (score 11):

since
$$\dfrac{1}{\log_{2}{\pi}}+\dfrac{1}{\log_{3}{\pi}}+\dfrac{1}{\log_{5}{\pi}}
=\log_{\pi}{2}+\log_{\pi}{3}+\log_{\pi}{5}=\log_{\pi}{(2\cdot 3\cdot 5)}
=\log_{\pi}{30}<\log_{\pi}{\pi^3}=3$$

Comment: I can't believe how easy it was. Thank you.

Comment: Nice inequality\;, Can we calculate $\lfloor \dfrac{1}{\log_{2}{\pi}}+\dfrac{1}{\log_{3}{\pi}}+\dfrac{1}{\log_{5}{\pi}} \rfloor$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1{\log_2 \pi} +\frac1{\log_3 \pi} +\frac1{\log_5 \pi} =$$
$$=\log_{\pi}2+\log_{\pi}3+\log_{\pi}5=\log_{\pi}30<\log_{\pi}\pi^3=3$$

Answer (score 1):

> Notice:
>
> - $$\frac{1}{\log_{a}(b)}=\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}$$
> - $$\ln(a)+\ln(b)=\ln(ab)$$
> - $$\exp\left[a\ln(b)\right]=b^a$$

$$\frac{1}{\log_{2}(\pi)}+\frac{1}{\log_{3}(\pi)}+\frac{1}{\log_{5}(\pi)}<3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(\pi)}+\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(\pi)}+\frac{\ln(5)}{\ln(\pi)}<3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln(2)+\ln(3)+\ln(5)}{\ln(\pi)}<3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln(2\cdot3\cdot5)}{\ln(\pi)}<3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln(30)}{\ln(\pi)}<3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln(30)<3\ln(\pi)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$30<\pi^3$$